# Displaying data from CMS_User in kentico

Tags: kentico

I have user control and I want to fill a drop-down list form control with CMS User table with a condition on it. could you please help me to do it. thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide code samples, tech stack etc, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Hi there, can you please let us know what version of Kentico you're using, whether you're using Portal or MVC, and also if you want to add that drop-down list to the live site, or to the admin site.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for ur responses. I'm using Portal, Kentico V10 and I wanna show the drop-down list in the live site. I choose my problem via searching through Kentico Devnet and the related code is here for someone who needs it ...

Answer (score -1):

for someone who needs, the answer is here (the where condition depends on the type of search you have, so I left it empty) :

```
    public void FillUsers()
{
    string where = "";
    var UserColumns = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers().Columns("UserID", "FullName", "BusinessUnitId").Where(where).OrderBy("asia_personalcode");        

    if (UserColumns != null)
    {

        DataSet ds = UserColumns;
        if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(ds))
        {
            cmbUser.DataSource = ds;
            cmbUser.DataTextField = "FullName";
            cmbUser.DataValueField = "UserID";
            cmbUser.DataBind();
            cmbUser.Items.Insert(0, "-");
            cmbUser.Items[0]``.Value = "";
        }
    }
}
```